# Refactoring firstReverse using each

Tags: refactoring, each

// Trying to Refactor the firstReverse function using each? // I Created a func that takes a str as a parameter, use firstReverse within // the for loop the output will be the reversed version of the string.

var stringName = "Matt";

var firstReverse = function(str){ var output = ""; for(var i = str.length -1; i >= 0; i--){ output+= str[i]; } return output; };

### firstReverse(stringName)

// Output: "ttaM"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var stringName="Matt";
function firstReverse(str)
{
    var newString="";
    str.split('').forEach(function(a){newString=a+newString});
    return newString;
}

document.getElementById('test')./*danger!!!*/innerHTML = firstReverse(stringName);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```